# Collision between two objects ndgmr.checkPixelCollision

Tags: createjs

I am trying to detect for a collision between two objects that are wrapped inside of two different containers. I am using a collision detection script found here https://github.com/olsn/Collision-Detection-for-EaselJS/tree/master/example/js.

I can get the ndgmr.checkRectCollision working but then the transparent areas of my bitmaps are also dectected in the the collision which is to be expected based on the documentation ;) Swapping over to ndgmr.checkPixelCollision is causing an error in my console.

```
 TypeError: image is undefined
 ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height);
```

Anyone found out what the error means and how to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I just created a get function in MyObject class that returns my Sprite.

```
 var obj01 = new MyObject(loader.getResult("myObj"), 50, 50);
 var obj02 = new MyObject(loader.getResult("myObj"), 50, 50);

 var collision = ndgmr.checkPixelCollision(obj01.getImage(),obj02.getImage(), 1);
```

Works perfectly!